# How to get the file name of the editor file into the multipage editor class which extends MultiPageEditorPart and implements IResourceChangeListener

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Basically i will be having n-different files of same type in a project.I want to retrieve the filenames of those files which will be currently calling the multipage editor class when we try to open a file.

Answer (score 0):

The `IEditorPart` for the editor has a `getEditorInput()` method that gives you the input to the editor.

The editor input may be an instance of `IFileEditorInput` in which case you can call the `getFile()` method.

The input might also be `IPathEditorInput` in which case you can use `getPath()`, or it might be `IURIEditorInput` which has `getURI()`.